# Most usable way to convert a non-associative array to an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I often need the functionality to convert an array to an associative array (often in order to be able to check for existance of an entry using `isset`).

Let me give an example:

```
$test = array("foo", "bar", "faz");
```

I'd like to convert this to something like:

```
$test = array("foo" => true, "bar" => true, "faz" => true);
```

I know of these techniques which (almost) achieve what I want to do, but I'm searching for something slick and more elegant than this:

```
$new = array();
foreach ($test as $v) $new[$v] = true; // want to do it without a loop

$new = array_flip($test); // works for isset but array_values($new) are all different

$new = array_map(function() { return true; }, array_flip($test)); // would work but verbose
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with a loop?  Seems to solve the problem.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? `array_search` will find specific values far more efficiently (and easily) than `isset` combined with any of these solutions. `if (array_search('foo', $test) !== false) { /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: An associative array is also a PHP array of course.!

Comment: @MatthewScharley how do you draw this conclusion? (benchmarks, implementation details of `array_search`)

Comment: @akirk: Simple deduction. A loop over an over a full array to test for the presence of an element (which is what `array_search` does) is obviously cheaper than looping over a full array, creating a second array with inverted elements and then testing for the presence of a key in the second array.

Comment: @MatthewScharley true if I just need to look up one value. But what if I need this when I loop over another array to check existence for the value in first array. I will have to call it over and over.

Comment: @akirk: Which comes back to my original question: "What are you actually trying to achieve?" Usage patterns do play a big part in what is the correct solution too. I wouldn't assume that looking up a hashtable for a key is faster than than searching through a (small) array either though. I'd be benchmarking both ways.

Comment: @MatthewScharley I agree. It all drills down to readability. It's probably just personal preference to use `isset` instead of `array_search`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$new = array_combine( $test, array_fill(0, count($test), true) );
```

Comment: would you add a reference to `array_fill_keys` so that I can accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, you just have to ask a question and then you find the answer yourself :-)

With PHP 5.2 you can do this:

```
$new = array_fill_keys($test, true);
```

below that version you can use this workaround:

```
$new = array_combine($test, array_fill(0, count($test), true));
```

Comment: I think your arguments are backwards in your `array_fill_keys()` example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_combine` together with `array_fill`

Answer (score 0):

> want to do it without a loop

Here goes a secret knowledge: every time you're messing with array, a loop involved. Even if you don't see it.

> works for isset but array_values($new) are all different

so what? what's the problem with these different values?

> would work but verbose

here goes another piece of secret knowledge: one can create a function. and hide as much code within it, as they wish.

Honestly, you've got your question out of nowhere. Don't you have no real problems to solve?

*BTW, from where did you get your initial array?*

Comment: actually the `array_fill_keys()` method is the elegant way to do it. It can be tremendously helpful to have an associative array at hand, for example when looping over another array and adding a value to first array just if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Example: `$tags = array_fill_keys(get_from_data_source(), true);
    foreach ($mytags as $tag) {
        if (isset($tags[$tag])) {
            // do x
        } else {
            $tags[$tag] = true;
        }
    }` (this is just an abstraction, I am talking about arrays of the size of 1000 elements)